# Result when subtrahend calls round function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm dividing two `floats`, multiplying it by 100 and then subtracting it by 100. I'm returning a percentage.

My question is: why is the final result a float that isn't rounded when the right part of the subtraction returns a float of 2 digits?

These is one sequence:

```
/* 1 */ 
-- Returns 0.956521739130435, which is correct.
select cast(198 as float)/(cast(198 as float) + cast(9 as float)) -- correct

/* 2 */ 
-- Returns 95.6521739130435, which is correct.
select 100*(cast(198 as float)/(cast(198 as float) + cast(9 as float))) --correct

/* 3 */ 
-- It's the same as previous one, but with a ROUND
-- Returns 95.65, which is correct.
select round(100*(cast(198 as float)/(cast(198 as float) + cast(9 as float))),2)

/* 4 */
-- Returns 4.34999999999999, should be 100-95.65, but it's not. ROUND is ignored. Why?
select 100-round(100*(cast(198 as float)/(cast(198 as float) + cast(9 as float))),2)
           |-------------- This returns 95.65 --------------------------------|
```

Another sequence:

```
/* 1 */ 
-- Returns 0.956521739130435, which is correct.
select cast(198 as float)/(cast(198 as float) + cast(9 as float))

/* 2 */ 
-- Returns 0.9565, which is correct.
select round(cast(198 as float)/(cast(198 as float) + cast(9 as float)), 4)

/* 3 */ 
-- Returns 95.65, which is correct.
select 100*round(cast(198 as float)/(cast(198 as float) + cast(9 as float)), 4)

/* 4 */
-- Returns 4.34999999999999, should be 100-95.65, but it's not. ROUND is ignored. Why?
select 100-(100*round(cast(198 as float)/(cast(198 as float) + cast(9 as float)), 4))
           |-------------------- This returns 95.65 --------------------------------|
```

I'm just curious as to why this happens, although it can easily be fixed with one `ROUND` at the beginning:

```
select round(100-(100*(cast(198 as float)/(cast(198 as float) + cast(9 as float)))), 2)
```

The reason I ask is because it's not something that can be easily reproduced. I tried reproducing it, and out of 2,000 times, it only occurred 12 times. That's less than 1%, but with floats with repetitive numbers after the 2nd decimal (ie. 3.47999999999), which makes sense:

```
declare @rand int = 1
While(@rand <= 2000)
begin
    select 100-round(100*(cast(abs(checksum(NewId()) % 1500) as float)/(cast(abs(checksum(NewId()) % 1500) as float) + cast(abs(checksum(NewId()) % 1500) as float))),2)
    set @rand = @rand + 1
end
```

I guess my other question is: what type is the sql editor returning when it returns *95.65* with `select round(100*(cast(198 as float)/(cast(198 as float) + cast(9 as float))),2)`?

Comment: In a nutshell, this happens because `SELECT 100e - 95.65e` gives `4.34999999999999`, due to the inability of `FLOAT` to represent `95.65` exactly. This is why the result needs to be rounded again if you want a "proper" result. `DECIMAL` has no such problem, which is why `SELECT 100 - 95.65` gives an exact result. The same does not happen with the 5th result simply because the string representation happens to round correctly. `SELECT FORMAT(100-(round(100*(cast(424 as float)/(cast(424 as float) + cast(1312 as float))),2)), 'G17')` will reveal the "actual" result: `75.579999999999998`.

Comment: `FORMAT` is not available on SQL Server 2008 -- `STR(x, 30, 17)` will achieve roughly the same, though.

Comment: Type `100-95.65` in your browser's JavaScript console and see what happens.

Comment: I get 4.349999999999994

Comment: But I don't need to round it twice. I just need to round the final result.

Comment: @fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf use DECIMAL data type. Not much of an answer but that is the answer.

Comment: This is because of the query plan, sql server decided another execution plan for the last SELECT. `SELECT CAST(100 - ( 100 *(198.0/(198 + 9 ))) AS DECIMAL(18,2) )` this is alternative method.

Comment: `Round` of a `float` returns a `float` which is an _approximate numeric type_. If you want the final result rounded then that is what you ought to round, but you'll still get a `float` unless you `cast` or `convert` to an _exact numeric type_, e.g. `decimal`.

Comment: "What type is the SQL editor returning" -- if you mean the engine, you can check with `SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(<expr>, 'BaseType')`. (Answer: `FLOAT`.) If you actually mean Management Studio, it's best not to rely on how it chooses to format `FLOAT` values (or any other values, for that matter), if you actually need a string representation. This is why `STR` exists. I *think* that recent versions will just give you whatever `Double.ToString` gives you, since they're .NET based. Internally, SQL Server passes the floating-point value with full fidelity to the client as a typed value.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Jeroen's comment:

SQL Server's `FLOAT` type is a double-precision floating-point value.  As with (most) floating point formats, the value is stored in binary.  Just as the number 1/3 cannot be represented with a finite number of digits after the decimal, the number 95.65 cannot be represented with a finite number of bits.  The closest value to 95.65 that can be stored in a `FLOAT` has the exact value:

```
95.650000000000005684341886080801486968994140625
```

If you subtract that number from 100, you get exactly:

```
4.349999999999994315658113919198513031005859375
```

When displayed, this is rounded to 15 significant digits, and the value printed is:

```
4.34999999999999
```

As discussed, you can solve this problem by using `DECIMAL` type instead of `FLOAT`.

There are many resources available on StackOverflow and elsewhere if you'd like to learn more about floating-point math.

**-- EDIT --**

I'm going to use parenthesis notation for repeating decimals. When I write

```
0.(3)
```

that means

`0.333333333333333333333333333...`  and so on forever.

Let's start at the beginning.  `168` can be stored in a `float`.  `168+9` is `177`. That can be stored in a `float`.  If you divide `168` by `177` the mathematically correct answer is:

```
0.95(6521739130434782608695)
```

But this value cannot be stored in a `float`. The closest value that can be stored in a float is:

```
0.9565217391304348115710354250040836632251739501953125
```

Take that number and multiply by `100` , the mathematically correct answer is:

```
95.65217391304348115710354250040836632251739501953125
```

Since you multiplied a `float` by `100`, you get a `float`, and that number cannot be stored in a `float`, so the closest possible value is:

```
95.6521739130434838216388016007840633392333984375
```

You ask that this `float` be rounded to 2 digits after the decimal.  The mathematically correct answer is:

```
95.65
```

But since you asked to round a `float`, the answer is also a `float`, and that value cannot be stored in a `float`.  The closest possible value is:

```
95.650000000000005684341886080801486968994140625
```

You asked to subtract that from `100`. The mathematically correct value is:

```
4.349999999999994315658113919198513031005859375
```

As it happens, that value *can* be stored in a `float`.  So that's the value that's being selected.

When converting this number to a string, SQL Server rounds the result to 15 significant digits.  So that number, when printed, appears as:

```
4.34999999999999
```

When you ran the same calculation on your Java console, the exact same calculations were performed, but when the value was printed, Java rounded to 16 significant digits:

```
4.349999999999994
```

**-- Another EDIT --**

Why can't `96.65` be stored exactly in a `float`?  The `float` type stores numbers in binary format.  If you want to express `96.65` in binary, the mathematically exact value is:

```
1011111.1010011001100110011001100110011001100110011001(1001)
```

You can see the pattern.  Just as 1/3 is represented as an infinite repeating value in decimal, this value has an infinite repeating value in binary.  You can see the pattern (1001) being repeated over and over.

A `float` can only hold `53` significant bits. And so this is rounded to:

```
1011111.1010011001100110011001100110011001100110011010
```

If you convert that number back to decimal, you get the exact value:

```
95.650000000000005684341886080801486968994140625
```

-- Yet Another Edit --

You ask what happens when you call Round again on the result.

We started with the number:

4.349999999999994315658113919198513031005859375

You ask that this be rounded to 2 places. The mathematically correct answer is:

4.35

Since you are rounding a float, this result must also be a float. Express this value in binary.  The mathematically correct answer is:

100.0101100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001(1001)

Again, this is a repeating binary value. But float can't store an infinite number of bits.  The value is rounded to 53 significant bits. The result is:

100.0101100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011

If you convert this to decimal, the exact value is:

4.3499999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375

That is the value you selected.  Now SQL Server needs to print that on the screen.  As before, it is rounded to 15 significant digits.  The result is:

4.35000000000000

It removes the trailing zeros, and the result you see on the screen is:

4.35

The last round did nothing magic.  The answer is still stored as a float, and the answer is still not an exact value.  As it happens SQL Server chooses to round values to 15 significant digits when printing a float.  In this case, that rounded value happened to match the exact value you were expecting.

If values were rounded to 14 places when printing them, the original query would have appeared to have the value you expected.

If values were rounded to 16 places, then the result of the final round would be shown as

4.3499999999999996

Comment: The question isn't about `float` types. It's about why the `ROUND` in `100-ROUND()` is being ignored. In both cases, the right part is returning a float with 2 decimals. I'll be editing the question.

Comment: The round DID work.  The value was rounded to 95.65.  But since the value is stored in a FLOAT, it could not hold that exact value.

Comment: So you're saying that at the of the day, the `ROUND(x, 2)` in  `select 100-ROUND(x, 2)` is not being evaluated even though `select ROUND(x, 2)` returns a rounded float?

Comment: The Round WAS evaluated.  The answer mathematically exactly correct result is 95.65.   That was corrected calculated.  But if you call ROUND on a  FLOAT, you get a FLOAT.  So that value, 95.65 is stored in a FLOAT.  But that exact value can't be stored in a float.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I edited the question since your reply makes sense.

Comment: What type is the sql editor returning with the `round`? It doesn't seem to represent the _real_ value, so to speak.

Comment: Small addendum: you *can* get SQL Server to print values itself (with `PRINT`), but usually what you'll see on the screen is whatever your client-side SQL tool chooses to show after it gets the value from the server. This is usually Management Studio, but it can be something else with different formatting policies. Incidentally, a great illustration of that is `PRINT 100e - 95.65e` vs. `SELECT 100e - 95.65e` -- my installation gives `4.35` for the former and `4.34999999999999` for the latter, but it's the same value.

Comment: If you found this explanation useful, could you accept it as the answer?